# Apache rewrite URL on querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the URL from the following

```
/live/select?wt=json&group=true&group.field=content-type&fl=id,content-type&q=*:*
```

to this

```
/live/select?wt=json&group=true&group.field=content_type&fl=id,content-type&q=*:*
```

Only the first occurrence of the **content-type** has to be change to **content_type**. Converting the hyper to a underscore.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /live/select\?wt=json&group=true&group\.field=content-type&fl=id,content-type&q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /live/select?wt=json&group=true&group.field=content-type&fl=id,content_type&q=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks Starkeen. Its working. But I need some additional help that the query string might have some double quotes and its getting encrypted. For example
/live/select?wt=json&group=true&group.field=content-type&fl=id,content-type&q=type:"content"
and during this case, its getting encrypted twice like type:%2522content%2522
Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Use a NE no escape flag in your Rule **[NE,NC,L,R]**